# display a loader when a built in Datatable button (PDF, Print etc) is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a *DataTable* which has buttons but due to the large amount of data in the table, when I click the buttons, it takes a while to download the PDF (for example), I was wondering if there is some sort of loader we can display.

Alternatively, I'm not sure how to display a loader which disappears when the action has finished (e.g. PDF button clicked, loader displayed, then hidden once PDF rendered in Adobe)

I have a custom loader I use when the table is loading on page load and hides when the table is loaded.

The code below for that:

**JS File**

```
..Other Datatable Code above This...
"initComplete": function () {
    $('#accountSearchDataTableLoader').hide();
},
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="accountSearchDataTableLoader">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border text-info" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

I need to identify when the PDF has rendered or the CSV is ready for download then hide the loader if I need to use my existing loader above

Comment: Hi Murday1983, do you have a more elaborate code example? Of the loading mechanic in particular. Maybe it provides a callback function or something that can be hooked on to show/hide content and therefore a more elaborate sample will help us to answer your query.

Comment: Does your button make an Ajax call? or Do you just click the button and render the PDF on the front-end?

Comment: @carkod It's the built in `Datatable` CSV, print, PDF buttons so clicking them just renders the whole `Datatable` data. No additional code front-end or `Ajax` etc

Comment: @StefanN The only thing i do with my current loader is as using the code i provided, on page load it displays the loader then when table loaded (initComplete) it hides the loader and displays the table instead.  No other code,  The buttons i am using are the built in `Datatable` buttons. I have no other code available